# Flutter BlocProvider of() called with a context that doesnt contain a bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

My Flutter app shows an error:
The following assertion was thrown building BlocBuilder<AlgorithmBloc, AlgorithmState>(dirty, state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<AlgorithmBloc, AlgorithmState>#d1b56):
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a GraphBloc.
The code of my main.dart:

```
MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider<GraphBloc>(
      create: (context) => GraphBloc(
        graphRepository: graphRepository,
      ),
    ),
    BlocProvider<AlgorithmBloc>(
      create: (context) => AlgorithmBloc(),
    ),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp...
```

This means that the BlocProviders are here. But when I go to my MainBody.dart file. I have nested BlocBuilders like this.

```
child: BlocBuilder<AlgorithmBloc, AlgorithmState>(
                bloc: BlocProvider.of<AlgorithmBloc>(context),
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is SelectedAlgorithm) {
                    currentAlgorithm = state.algorithmName;
                  }
                  return BlocBuilder<GraphBloc, GraphState>(
                    bloc: BlocProvider.of<GraphBloc>(context),
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is EmptyGraph) {
                        BlocProvider.of<GraphBloc>(context).add(GetDefaultGraph());
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                        );
                      }
```

Here is an Image from the error.
[Bloc Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK723.png)

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: The BlocBuiilders must be in another Stateless / Stateful widget than the Multi Blocprovider widget

Comment: They are, The Blocprovider is in main.dart. and the Builders are in mainbody.dart which is another widget

Comment: nesting bloc providers seems like a bad idea.  why do it

Answer (score 0):

the concrete class myClass is extended from Bloc which receive an event.  The myClass has a stream method with an async* and yield putting data back on the stream after applying the business logic.  A BlocProv manages communication between the myClass and the a Widget through context.bloc allowing the widget to communicate with the bloc stream through events and receive datastream data.